# Error properties not defined when pointing to a local variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, configuration, scope

I have the following configuration file :

```
/* env.js */

ENV_TO_USE = [
"local"
];

// local; dev; rec; pre; prod
module.exports = {
    env_properties : {
        local : {
            root_url : "localhost",
            port : 3000,
            root_dir : "/home/user/project/"
        },
        dev : {
            root_url : "devdomain",
            port : 3000,
            root_dir : "/apps/project/",
        }
    },
    global_properties : {
        path_include :
        {
            PATH_EXPRESS : env_properties[ENV_TO_USE].root_dir + 'express'
        }
    }
};
```

And in another file, I want to print the 'PATH_EXPRESS' value :

```
/* test.js */

var env = require('./env.js');
console.log(env.global_properties.path_include.PATH_EXPRESS);
```

But when I launch the script with the command **node test.js**, I get the following error :

```
PATH_EXPRESS : env_properties[ENV_TO_USE].root_dir + 'express'
                       ^
ReferenceError: env_properties is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\user\project\env.js:23:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\user\project\test.js:1:73)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

I still want to keep one single file, and not creating a second file.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: Thanks, but the answer of @user1280859 it more suitable to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* env.js */
ENV_TO_USE = [
"local"
];

var env_properties = {
        local : {
            root_url : "localhost",
            port : 3000,
            root_dir : "/home/user/project/"
        },
        dev : {
            root_url : "devdomain",
            port : 3000,
            root_dir : "/apps/project/",
        }
    }

// local; dev; rec; pre; prod
module.exports = {
    env_properties : env_properties,
    global_properties : {
        path_include :
        {
            // and you have to specify which env you want to use
            PATH_EXPRESS : env_properties[0].root_dir + 'express'
        }
    }
};
/* No need to export the env_properties since it is included in the scope */
```